# Error launching application after migration from Vaadin 14 to Vaadin 24

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

I've tried migrating an old application from vaadin 14 to 24 using
https://vaadin.com/docs/v23/upgrading/essential-steps
followed by
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/upgrading

I've manage to resolved most of the issues but I've encountered one that I don't understand. When I launch the application, it fails on startup with the following stacktrace

```
07-Nov-2023 09:36:14.446 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Erreur lors de l'invocation de la mÃ©thode [manageApp]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Erreur lors du dÃ©marrage du conteneur fils
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1821)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:376)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Echec de dÃ©marrage du composant [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myApp]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Vite build exited with a non zero status
        at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.runNodeTasks(DevModeInitializer.java:357)
        at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.lambda$initDevModeHandler$0(DevModeInitializer.java:293)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run$$$capture(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec$$$capture(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
    Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Vite build exited with a non zero status
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunDevBundleBuild.runFrontendBuildTool(TaskRunDevBundleBuild.java:187)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunDevBundleBuild.execute(TaskRunDevBundleBuild.java:99)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:312)
        at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.runNodeTasks(DevModeInitializer.java:352)
        ... 10 more
07-Nov-2023 09:36:14.449 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Erreur lors de l'invocation de la mÃ©thode [createStandardContext]
    javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Erreur lors de l'invocation de la mÃ©thode [manageApp]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:304)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:376)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Erreur lors du dÃ©marrage du conteneur fils
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1821)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        ... 34 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Echec de dÃ©marrage du composant [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myApp]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        ... 42 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Vite build exited with a non zero status
        at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.runNodeTasks(DevModeInitializer.java:357)
        at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.lambda$initDevModeHandler$0(DevModeInitializer.java:293)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run$$$capture(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec$$$capture(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
    Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Vite build exited with a non zero status
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunDevBundleBuild.runFrontendBuildTool(TaskRunDevBundleBuild.java:187)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskRunDevBundleBuild.execute(TaskRunDevBundleBuild.java:99)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:312)
        at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.runNodeTasks(DevModeInitializer.java:352)
        ... 10 more
```

By putting a breakpoint on that exeption I've managed to get this error that was not in my logs

```
vite v4.4.11 building for production...
transforming...

images/home.jpg referenced in [Path to my app]/frontend/styles/styles.css?used&inline didn't resolve at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime
✓ 203 modules transformed.
✓ built in 2.07s
[commonjs--resolver] Missing "./directives/class-map" specifier in "lit-html" package
error during build:
Error: Missing "./directives/class-map" specifier in "lit-html" package
    at e (file:///[Path to my app]/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:21445:25)
    at n (file:///[Path to my app]/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:21445:627)
    at o (file:///[Path to my app]/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:21445:1297)
    at resolveExportsOrImports (file:///[Path to my app]/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:28741:20)
    at resolveDeepImport (file:///[Path to my app]/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:28760:31)
    at tryNodeResolve (file:///[Path to my app]/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:28448:20)
    at Object.resolveId (file:///[Path to my app]/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:28207:28)
    at file:///[Path to my app]/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25544:40
    at async PluginDriver.hookFirstAndGetPlugin (file:///[Path to my app]/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25444:28)
    at async resolveId (file:///[Path to my app]/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24117:26)
```

What I don't understand is that if I check in 'node_modules\lit-html\directives' I find:

- class-map.d.ts
- class-map.d.ts.map
- class-map.js

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you done a full clean (depending on your build-tool)? The one, that removes all generated files and node and what-not.

Comment: Just to be sure, I've tried cleaning the whole project once again but I still get the same error.

Comment: I've re-run the build-front end goal that was causing an error without changing anything and this time it worked... I tried once again to clean and rebuild and it worked without any issues... Time to work on the next migration issue.